# search and replace with line in document

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that searches and replaces with a line in the document. i have:

```
import re
x = open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt')
string = open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt').read()
Lines = x.readlines()
new_str = re.sub('zzz1', (Lines[1]) , string)
new_str = re.sub('zzz2', (Lines[2]) , string)

open(r'F:\1\xxx2.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

in xxx1 document i have written for testing

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
zzz1
zzz2
```

but the output I get in xxx2 document is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
zzz1
3
```

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `new_str = re.sub('zzz2', (Lines[2]) , string)`: you're overwriting `new_str` at this point... not sure that it's the sole issue given that the code is particularly complex and hard to read

Comment: Since you've already read the entire file using `.read()` when you do a `.readlines()` on it - `Lines` should be an empty list and you should be getting `IndexError`s - are you sure this is the code you're running?

Comment: definitely the code im running. no doubt im over writing previous replace why only zzz2 is replaced. hwo can i make the code do two search and replace and.why is zzz2 replaced with the third line and not the second?

Comment: so putting (Lines[0]) replaces with the first line. thats one answer. any idea how can i do it several times for several searches and lines? and how can i replace without the blank line to follow?

Comment: why reading `'F:\1\xxx.txt'` twice, once for contents & once for lines? it's really underperformant and confusing. What do you want to achieve? expected output? I admit I'm lost here (the fact that noone answered proves my point ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working solution:

import re
x = open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt')
Lines = x.readlines()

repldict = {'zzz1':(Lines[0]).strip(), 'zzz2':(Lines[1]).strip()}
def replfunc(match):
    return repldict[match.group(0)]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in repldict))
with open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt') as fin, open(r'F:\1\xxx2.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))